# IllegalAccessError on @Around - Aspectj

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj

When calling this AspectJ `@Around` function:

```
@Around("controllers() && methodsPointcut()")
    public Object returnControlerLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object value = joinPoint.proceed();
        this.log(LogTypes.CONTROLLER, value, joinPoint.getTarget().getClass(), "CONTROLLER RETURN",
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        return value;
    }
```

I got

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class my.aspect.package.LogAspect$LogTypes from class my.controller.package.MyController
```

While inside this Spring function controller's pointed by the pointcut:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/doSth")
public @ResponseBody JSONObject doSth(@RequestParam String sth) {
 return new JSONObject().put("key", sth);
}
```

I just adapted this [example](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html) to my needs.

I have other pointcut as `@Before` or `@AfterThrowing` that works well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the most important part of your code. I see not package names, no class declaration, no aspect declaration, just snippets. Next time please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so as to keep people from doing what I am about to do now: guessing instead of reproducing and providing solid answers.

So my educated guess is that you have not declared your aspect public. Please do and be happy.

Comment: Hi kriegaex, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I've been busy on work and forgot to post the solution. I'll post it as soon as possible providing also a detailed explanation of my problem.